# NgIf and NgSwitch in Typescript Instead of Html Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

Is it good practice to utilize Html *NgIf and *NgSwitch in Angular? If someone does this, both business rendering logic is in the front-end html files, and the backend .ts files.

Additionally, business logic is split in two area layers.

Does Angular have any typescript ts file way of using NgIf, instead of utilizing html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is good practise to utilize `*ngIf` and `*ngSwitch` in Angular. Backend code is to use on the server. Secure. Angular is to use for front-end applications; the client side. Security wise, it doesn't matter if you use your logic in HTML or TypeScript to display data.

You should try and learn the basics of Angular. Maybe an online course.